# How do I plot multiple time series from a Dataset?

Tags: plotting, dataset, date-and-time

I have a `Dataset` `ds` with a straightforward tabular structure containing one column `Date` whose values are `DateObject`s, and a number of other columns of real-valued numbers.

I can plot the value of *one* of these columns using:

```
DateListPlot[ds[All,{"Date","Column1"}]]
```

This plots the values in `Column1` against an X-axis using the dates from `Date` as expected:

[image: 1]

How can I extend this behaviour to display lines for more than one column?

Attempting:

```
DateListPlot[ds[All,{"Date","Column1","Column2"}]]
```

results in:

> **DateListPlot:** Unable to automatically determine horizontal coordinates for the given data and DataRange.

Attempting:

```
DateListPlot[ds[All,{"Date",#}]& /@ {"Column1","Column2"}]
```

> **DateListPlot:**
>    `{ Dataset[<<150>>] , Dataset[<<150>>] }` is not a valid dataset or list of datasets.

Is there an adjustment to either of these input approaches that will fix the flaws in my approach, or if not how *can* this be achieved?

Comment: `DateListPlot[{ds1, ds2}]`

Comment: `ds[All, {"Date", {"c1",  "c2"}}] // DateListPlot[#,  Joined -> False]&`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The query `ds[All,{"Date","Column1"}]` returns a list of associations whose values represent date-value pairs.  The query `ds[All, "Date", "Column1", "Column2"}]` returns a list of associations with multiple values for each date.  `DateListPlot` will accept the first format, but not the second.

To plot multiple series, we must reformat the data into a shape that is acceptable to `DateListPlot`.  For example, we could generate multiple lists of date-value pairs:

```
ds[Transpose /* DateListPlot, {{#Date, #Column1}, {#Date, #Column2}}&]
```

**Discussion**

For discussion purposes, we will define a sample dataset:

```
ds = Range[5] // Query[Dataset
     , <| "date" -> (DatePlus["2005-01-01", {#, "Year"}]&)
        , "v1" -> Sin
        , "v2" -> Cos
        , "v3" -> Sec|>
     ]
```

[image: sample dataset]

As noted in the question, we can plot a single column of values easily:

```
ds[DateListPlot, {"date", "v1"}]
```

[image: single column plot]

but the same technique fails for multiple columns:

```
ds[DateListPlot, {"date", "v1", "v2"}]
```

[image: failure message]

The reason is that `DateListPlot` can handle the date-value pairs that are returned by the first query:

```
ds[First /* Values, {"date", "v1"}] // Normal
(* <|"date" -> "Sun 1 Jan 2006 00:00:00", "v1" -> Sin[1]|> *)
```

But `DateListPlot` does not presently (V11.1) accept an association with more than one value per date as is returned by the second query:

```
ds[First, {"date", "v1", "v2"}] // Normal
(* <|"date" -> "Sun 1 Jan 2006 00:00:00", "v1" -> Sin[1], "v2" -> Cos[1]|> *)
```

To plot multiple columns, we must reshape the data to conform to one of the formats acceptable to `DateListPlot`.  For example, it will accept multiple lists of date-values pairs:

```
ds[Transpose /* DateListPlot, {{#date, #v1}, {#date, #v2}, {#date, #v3}} &]
```

[image: multi-column plot]

Alternatively:

```
ds[(Query[All, {"date", #} /* Values] & /@ {"v1", "v2", "v3"}) /* DateListPlot]
```

In both queries we had to take care that the date-value pairs were lists -- not associations.  This is due to another limitation of `DateListPlot`.  While `DateListPlot` will accept a single set of associations containing date-value pairs, it cannot presently handle a list of such sets.  We must convert the associations to lists to work around this restriction.

Comment: How to add Plotstyle,PlotLabel etc, I tried DateListPlot[Plotstyle->...] but failed

Comment: @fairytale Use `(DateListPlot[#, PlotLabel -> "My Plot"] &)`.  The parentheses are important.

Comment: @WReach, I have this dataset ([csv file](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/244866/34223) in the post and `d` is the dataset imported using the code shown in the post.). When I tried your method of `DateListPlot` on my data. Unfortunately, `d[DateListPlot, {1, 2}]` or `DateListPlot@d[All, {1, 2}]` did not work for me and returned the same error of `Horizontal coordinate…`. While `DateListPlot@d[{1;;-1}, {1, 2}]` worked. Could you please help me out here? Thanks.

Comment: @Bemtevi77 `DateListPlot` has complicated set of rules for parsing the data argument... it must handle lists, lists of lists, wrapper objects and so on.  It uses heuristics to determine how to interpret the data and I think that the combination of associations containing dimensioned quantities is confusing it (bug?).  When we wrap an extra list around the data (as per your working example) then the possibilities are narrowed and it correctly parses out the date and value elements.  Other alternatives: `d[DateListPlot[{#}] &]`, `d[List/*DateListPlot]`.

Comment: @WReach Thank you very much for the explanation. I thought that was a bug.

Comment: @WReach: Was the limitation (you describe above) solved in version 11.3? I have the exact same problem using version 11.3.

Comment: @TugrulTemel Unfortunately, the CSV file that the OP linked to demonstrate the problem is gone and I can't remember the exact shape of that dataset.  So I cannot check whether 11.3 has the problem we were talking about.  I just now tried an association containing `Quantity` expressions and it seemed to work in 11.3.  You might consider posting a new question with your particular data (rather than us trying to go back and forth in these comments).

Comment: @WReach: Thanks for your clarifications. Actually, following your suggestion, I posted a new question yesterday. You might want to look at it when you have time. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

```
 ds = Dataset[{
    <|"Date" -> DateObject[{2016, 6, 28}], "c1" -> 10, "c2" -> 30, "c3" -> 0|>,
    <|"Date" -> DateObject[{2016, 6, 29}], "c1" -> 20, "c2" -> 20, "c3" -> 30|>,
    <|"Date" -> DateObject[{2016, 6, 30}], "c1" -> 30, "c2" -> 10, "c3" -> 0|>}]
```

[image]

```
DateListPlot[
 Values @ Normal @ ds[All, {"Date", #}] & /@ {"c1", "c2", "c3"},
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
 PlotLegends -> {"c1", "c2", "c3"}]
```

[image]

```
cplot[d_Dataset, c_?VectorQ] :=
 DateListPlot[
  Values @ Normal @ d[All, {"Date", #}] & /@ c,
  PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
  PlotLegends -> c]

cplot[ds, {"c1", "c3"}]
```

[image]

Comment: I have a grouped dataset: `jdatagrouped = 
  jdata[GroupBy[{#country &, #vars &}] /* KeySort, All, 
   All, {DateObject[{Round@#time}], #data} &]`. How can I use `DateListPlot` to generate plots for two countries across two variables on the same plot?