# Datelistplot and datasets. Plotting several time series with mapping functions and adding options

Tags: plotting, dataset

Following the post [How do I plot multiple time series from a Dataset?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/151918), I have additional questions.

I have a dataset with four columns. First is the date. 2nd to 4th are values (v1,v2 and v3).

Considering three different functions (let's say f,g,h), how to plot with datelistplot simultaneously f[v1],g[v2],h[v3] without reconstructing/modifying or adding new columns to the dataset. I want also to add some options and labels (plotrange...etc) to the plot.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you share a (sample) dataset for us to play with?

Comment: Consider this as well: if `ds` is your Dataset object, then `ds[All, {2 -> f, 3 -> g, 4 -> h}]` will generate a new Dataset in which function `f` has been applied to column 1, function `g` to column 2, and function `h` to column 3. Then you can proceed as indicated in the post you linked.