# Dataset: selectively map a function onto the nth column

Tags: dataset

I have this [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NXV80UjiL0WrB3S4J_y950C0-51C63JM/view?usp=sharing), which I used the following to `Import`.

```
c=Import["data1.csv", "Dataset", HeaderLines -> 1];
d=c[All, {1 -> ToExpression}];
```

[image]

I want to convert the 1st col to `Minute` and want to use the `dataset[All,{n->f}]` mentioned in MMA's `Dataset` document. My idea to operate a function on the 1st col and return a **two-col** dataset. I tried the following. Some worked, while some did not. Could you please have a check and comment on why some methods did not return what I want. Thanks.

Those worked.

```
f = UnitConvert[#, "Minutes"] &;
d[All, {1 -> f}]
d[All, {"t" -> f}]

d[All, {"t" -> Function[{x}, UnitConvert[x, "Minutes"]]}]
```

Those did not.

```
d[All, {1 -> UnitConvert[#, "Minutes"] &}] (*I understand why this one did not work.*)
d[All, {1 -> UnitConvert[#[[1]], "Minutes"] &}]
d[All, {"t" -> UnitConvert[#[[1]], "Minutes"] &}]
```

This simply blowed my mind. I wanted to return the 1st col itself. However, `1` seems to work as `#[[1]]` and `2` as `#[[2]]`. It seems to me anything appears on the right hand left is treated as a `Function` (Here, as `Part`)?

```
d[All, {"t" -> 1}]
d[All, {"t" -> 2}]
```

Comment: try `d[All, {1 -> (UnitConvert[#, "Minutes"] &)}]`?

Comment: (To see this, note that `a -> b & // FullForm` is `Function[Rule[a,b]]`, while `a -> (b &) // FullForm` is `Rule[a,Function[b]]`)

Comment: Thank you both! Now I understand why those did not work.